# rigid body marble run - does not allow me to complete a loop in the track

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have created the beginnings of a marble run using blender 3.1 and rigid bodies. For the run, I extruded a circle along a path. For the marble, I am using a scaled icosphere. I can get the marble to roll down the run, but when it gets to a short loop I built into the run, it stalls and will not go all the way around the loop, falling back and rocking back and forth until it stops. No matter what parameters I try, it won't work. I don't think the loop is too big. I have a long steep slope leading into it. I am beginning to think it is a limitation of rigid bodies. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Running blender 3.1 on a windows system with a graphics card.

Here is a copy of the blender file. \

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k6v2nyy52wwmz5/marble_run.blend?dl=0

Comment: It's possible the shape of the icosphere doesn't handle a loss in velocity and/or change in direction well. Maybe try using a "quad-sphere" for the marble instead - Start with a cube, then add a _subdivision Surface Modifier_ level 3, and a _Cast Modifier_ with the _Factor_ set to 1. Apply them both.

Comment: i think there are two reasons why it won't work. First you have friction of ball and marble run set to 5. These should be as low as possible. Second the geometry of your marble run is ridiculous high which makes it hard for Blender physics to calculate. "normally" a density like this is more than enough for blender physics: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci9yr.png if this isn't enough for your render, maybe make a second one with higher density for render and for the physics the low poly one invisible.

Comment: @Chris, I've tried your solution but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @moonboots : can u provide blend file so I can check it?

Comment: @Chris https://blend-exchange.com/b/jX1pJ44A

Comment: although i am pretty sure you don't wanna here it... ;) it works, if you lengthen the middle part a "bit" so that the ball gets more speed:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8expa.gif. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=y7mxZWe7" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/y7mxZWe7/)

Comment: @Chris Great, but I guess RAMickelsen wanted a trick to make it work as it is, that said, maybe write the answer  ;)

Comment: Well …sometimes you might beat physics - but in the real world, physics beats you!‍♂️

Comment: @Chris Is Blender the real world? Are we living in a blend file? How many polygons are you made of? Why are my normals inverted? i'm confused now

Comment: There is not real world for „us“. We are living in a simulation (and we are doing bad…so I don’t think we are gonna make it). to your second question: so we ARE indeed living in a kind of blend file of the future which also can simulate smell, feelings, sounds and so on. I am probably made of 3 trillions peribets (which is the synonym of poligon in the future but which is too hard to explain to the human brain power‍♂️). You wouldn’t believe: peribets can also be inverted: that’s known for you as disease. Of course you are confused: you are human. That’s your nature.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the excellent input. I messed around with the friction settings and that did not solve the problem. I guess the solution is a longer run into the loop. Like you said, physics. And you are right. Too many subdivisions. Live and learn.

You guys are awesome.

BTW, I love this program. It is my new hobby. I am 70 years old, retired, and love computer graphics. I have another blender marble run up and working so this project is kaput.

Comment: Hi @RAMickelsen  I'm in my 80's and came across Blender some 6 years ago and finished up ditching the commercial stuff, using Blender exclusively.  I'd wager that dementia is kept at bay the more you use it! :)

Comment: Thanks Edgel3D! Guess Blender is not just for young folks!